# Failed to install Composer Azure Server

Tags: php, azure

I'm trying install composer on azure portal from extension and it throw:

> Failed to install Composer - ExitCode: -1073741819, Output:
>   D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension># Install Composer
>   D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension>cd Commands
>   D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Commands>IF EXIST
>   composer.phar (rm -f composer.phar )
>   D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Commands>IF NOT EXIST
>   "D:\local\AppData\Composer" (mkdir "D:\local\AppData\Composer" )
>   D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Commands>IF NOT EXIST
>   "D:\local\LocalAppData\Composer" (mkdir
>   "D:\local\LocalAppData\Composer" )
>   D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Commands>php -r
>   "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php, Error: '#' is
>   not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file., Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.CommandLineException: '#' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file. D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\install.cmd at
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteInternal(ITracer tracer,
>   Func`2 onWriteOutput, Func`2 onWriteError, Encoding encoding, String
>   arguments, Object[] args) at
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteWithProgressWriter(ILogger
>   logger, ITracer tracer, String arguments, Object[] args) at
>   Kudu.Core.SiteExtensions.SiteExtensionManager.<>c__DisplayClass25_1.b__1()
>   at
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.OperationManager.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()
>   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.OperationManager.Attempt[T](Func`1 action,
>   Int32 retries, Int32 delayBeforeRetry, Func`2 shouldRetry) at
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.OperationManager.Attempt(Action action, Int32
>   retries, Int32 delayBeforeRetry) at
>   Kudu.Core.SiteExtensions.SiteExtensionManager.d__25.MoveNext() --- End
>   of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Kudu.Core.SiteExtensions.SiteExtensionManager.d__24.MoveNext()

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In my test, it seems due to the build in PHP runtime version. I will reproduce your issue if I set the PHP version to 7.1 in Azure portal. But the composer extension will be installed fine if I downgrade the build in PHP version to 7.0.

So currently, you can downgrade the PHP runtime to 7.0 as a workaround. Or try to manually download [composer.phar](http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar) extension in your project.